# Problem saving ManyToMany relation in MySQL database via microservices

Tags: mysql, typescript, microservices, nestjs, typeorm

I have a relationship created between User and Groups, where a group can contain multiple users and a user can be present in more than one group. The relationship was built on the UserEntity and GroupsEntity entities. The problem occurs when the request is made in Postman. The User record is created, but the ids corresponding to the relationship between groups and user are not created in the new table (relationship of the two entities).

Help codes:

**UserEntitity.ts**

```
import { AssociateEntity } from 'src/associate/entities/associate.entity';
import { Associate } from 'src/associate/interfaces/associate.interface';
import { GroupsEntity } from 'src/groups/entities/group.entity';
import { Groups } from 'src/groups/interfaces/groups.interface';
import { SubsidiaryEntity } from 'src/subsidiary/entities/subsidiary.entity';
import { Subsidiary } from 'src/subsidiary/interfaces/subsidiary.interface';
import {
  Column,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinTable,
  ManyToMany,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  login: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  adm: boolean;

  @Column()
  passwordValidity: string;

  @Column()
  initials: string;

  @Column()
  system: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => SubsidiaryEntity, (subsidiary) => subsidiary.id)
  subsidiary: Subsidiary;

  @ManyToMany(() => GroupsEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  group: Groups[];

  @Column({ default: true })
  status: boolean;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => AssociateEntity, (associate) => associate.id)
  associate: Associate[];
}
```

**GroupsEntity.ts**

```
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/entities/user.entity';
import { User } from 'src/user/interfaces/user.interface';
import {
  Column,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  ManyToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class GroupsEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  status: boolean;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.group)
  user: User;
}
```

**user.service.ts** (method create)

```
async create(user: User) {
    try {
      const groups: Array<Groups> = await this.groupService.findByIds(
        user.groups,
      );
      //@ts-ignore
      user.groups = groups;
      const newUser = await this.userRepository.save(user);
      return newUser;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error.message)}`);
      throw new RpcException(error.code + error.message);
    }
  }
```

**The structure of the bank is given by:**
[Bank entity relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErZyW.png)

The code doesn't report errors, but it doesn't create the relationship with the ids either. I'm using microservices in nestJS, the language is TypeScript and the database used is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Join table you have define the join Column and inverseJoinColumn Details. Example

```
@JoinTable({
    name: 'cat_use_cloth',
    joinColumn: { name: 'cat_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'},
    inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'cloth_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'},
})
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@rodrigo.tornaciole/nest-js-many-to-many-relationship-using-typeorm-and-crud-ec6ed79274f0